# Can't delete a Stateful Set in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I can't delete this Stateful Set in Kubernetes, even with `--cascade=false` so it doesn't delete the Pods managed by it.

```
kubectl get statefulsets

NAME                        DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE
assets-elasticsearch-data   0         1         31m
```

Then:

```
kubectl delete statefulsets assets-elasticsearch-data
^C
```

... hangs for minutes until I give up, then:

```
kubectl delete statefulsets assets-elasticsearch-data --cascade=false
statefulset "assets-elasticsearch-data" deleted
kubectl get statefulsets
NAME                        DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE
assets-elasticsearch-data   0         1         32m
```

I'm using Google's GKE.

Comment: Can you check the node log file for any error message?

Comment: try `kubectl get events` and look for useful information.
try creating a deployment and deleting that to try and narrow down the source of the problem.
the `--cascade=false` shouldn't matter in the general deletion of the statefulset, like you said it's just an option.
while it's deployed, are the pods healthy and behaving as expected?
if all else fails, share your yaml file

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar issue with k8s 1.8. Tried many times and it timedout. 
Eventually I tried,

```
kubectl delete statefulsets mariadb -n openstack --force
```

*error: timed out waiting for "mariadb" to be synced*

This appears to work :

```
kubectl delete statefulsets mariadb -n openstack --force --grace-period=0 --cascade=false
```

*warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.*

*statefulset "mariadb" deleted*

Comment: I your version without the openstack argument worked perhps you can add it as a version

Answer (score 2):

I could reproduce the bug twice with Kubernetes `1.7.3` and, after destroying the cluster for the 3rd time and downgrading to Kubernetes `1.6.7`, I had no problem deleting `Stateful Sets` or Helm deployments ([Elasticsearch Helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/incubator/elasticsearch) in my case).

Answer (score 1):

Try the delete action again with `--grace-period=0` and `--force`.

Answer (score 1):

If the mentioned force flags don't work, I would suggest looking at the yaml metadata block and delete any existing finalizers as well as setting blockOwnerDelete to false, then retry deleting.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i was using an old version of kubectl.

i instaled a recent one on centos via yum and the problem is solved, i am able to delete the stalled statefulset

```
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo

[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
repo_gpgcheck=0
```